# Como posso interagir com uma classe que está por detrás de duas?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, lista, dicionário

Boa noite!

Passo a explicar o problema uma vez que o titulo não é sugestivo do mesmo. Eu tenho que desenvolver um sistema de compras online, capaz de gerir as compras de cada utilizador. Se pensarmos um pouco, fisicamente existe um shopping, ou mais, e existe por cada shopping varios carrinhos. Para este último caso, o dos carrinhos eu estou a implementar uma `List`.

É preciso termos em conta que estou a programar tendo em conta o conceito de programação por camadas, e a classe `Carrinhos`, bem como `Produto` estão na parte que diz respeito ao BO (*Buisness Object*)

Vendo um pouco a minha classe Carrinhos que está no BO temos:

1. Uma lista `List<Produto> listaProdutos;` de `Produtos`;
2. Construtores e propriedades (obrigatoriamente)
3. Métodos essenciais a manipulação da lista existente, como

   ```
       public bool AddProduto(Produto p)
       {
            if (!listaProdutos.Contains(p))
            {
                   listaProdutos.Add(p);
                   return true;
            }
           else
                   throw new ImpossivelExistirProdutosIguaisException();


       }

       public bool RemoveProduto(Produto p)
       {
           if(listaProdutos.Contains(p))//Se está lá um produto
           {
               listaProdutos.Remove(p);
               return true;
           }
           else
               throw new ProdutoNaoExisteNoCarrinho();

       }
   ```

A partir da DL, (*Data Layer*) eu entro nesta classe e adiciono, ou removo carrinhos a um determinado supermercado (Classe: `Shopping`). Na *Data Layer* eu trabalho com uma classe onde implemento um Dicionário de `Shoppings` em que o nome do shopping é a `key`, `static Dictionary<string,Shopping> sistemaDeCompras = new Dictionary<string, Shopping>();`

Esquematicamente o que se passa é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, como posso verificar se um determinado shopping existe, se determinado carrinho e existe e se ambos existirem, como posso adicionar produtos?

Deixo aqui tambem a minha DL para análise:

```
  static Dictionary<string,Shopping> sistemaDeCompras = new Dictionary<string, Shopping>();


        public static bool CriarShopping(Shopping sh, string nome)
        {
            if (!sistemaDeCompras.ContainsKey(nome))
            {
                sistemaDeCompras.Add(nome, sh);
                return true;
            }
            return false;   
        }

        public static bool RemoveShopping(string nome)
        {

            if (sistemaDeCompras.ContainsKey(nome))
            {
                sistemaDeCompras.Remove(nome);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        public static bool InsereCarrinho(Carrinho c, string nomeShopping)
        {
            if (sistemaDeCompras.ContainsKey(nomeShopping)) 
            {

                return sistemaDeCompras[nomeShopping].AddCarrinho(c);
                //GravaCarrosEstacionados("Park.f");

            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que você está querendo, pois pelo que entendi isso é bem fácil.

```
// Se você quer analisar se determinado shopping e carrinho está contido num dicionário.
public static bool Analise (Carrinho c, string shopping) {
    if (sistemaDeCompras.ContainsKey(nome)){
        return (sistemaDeCompras["nome"].Contains(c)) ? true : false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void Adicionar (){
    Carrinho meuCarrinho = new Carrinho();
    if (Analise(meuCarrinho, "Algum shopping que você queira")){
        meuCarrinho.AddProduto("Algum produto que você queira");
    }
    else {
        throw new CarrinhoOuShoppingNaoExistente();
    }
}
```

Eu acho que é isso que você quer, mas caso não seja, acho que já deu alguma ideia.